# Parallel.ForEach CancellationTokenSource not Stopping

Tags: c#, parallel-processing, cancellationtokensource

I'm currently writing a ProxyChecker library.
I'm using a Thread that funs a Parallel.ForEach loop to check all proxies.
I'm using a `CancellationTokenSource` (cts) to make a soft abort (with `cts.Cancel()`).
As u can see in the following code I added a little "test code" which writes the current Threads to the Console.

Here is the code u need:

```
private void CheckProxies(string[] proxies, int timeout, int threads, string domainToCheckWith)
        {
            _cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
            int checkedProxyCount = 0, uncheckedProxyCount = proxies.Length, goodProxies = 0, badProxies = 0;
            mainThread = new Thread(() =>
            {
                try
                {
                    Parallel.ForEach(proxies, new ParallelOptions {MaxDegreeOfParallelism = threads, CancellationToken = _cts.Token}, prox =>
                    {
                        Interlocked.Increment(ref running);
                        Console.WriteLine("thread running: {0}", running);
                        try
                        {
                            _cts.Token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
                            if (CheckProxy(prox, domainToCheckWith, timeout))
                            {
                                Interlocked.Increment(ref checkedProxyCount);
                                Interlocked.Increment(ref goodProxies);
                                Interlocked.Decrement(ref uncheckedProxyCount);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                Interlocked.Increment(ref checkedProxyCount);
                                Interlocked.Decrement(ref uncheckedProxyCount);
                                Interlocked.Increment(ref badProxies);
                            }
                            _cts.Token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
                            OnUpdate(uncheckedProxyCount, checkedProxyCount, goodProxies, badProxies);
                        }
                        catch (OperationCanceledException ex) {}
                        catch (ObjectDisposedException ex) {}
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            OnLog(ex.Message, Color.Red);
                        }
                        finally
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("thread running: {0}", running);
                            Interlocked.Decrement(ref running);
                        }
                    });
                }
                catch (OperationCanceledException ex) {}
                catch (ObjectDisposedException ex) {}
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    OnLog(ex.Message, Color.Red);
                }
                finally
                {
                    isRunning = false;
                    OnComplete();
                }
            });
            mainThread.Start();
        }
```

The output (I took out a few lines since it's useless to give u the full code)

```
thread running: 1
thread running: 1
thread running: 2
thread running: 2

//Slowly going up to  50

thread running: 50
thread running: 50
thread running: 50

//Staying at 50 till I press stop

thread running: 50
thread running: 50
thread running: 50
thread running: 50
thread running: 50
thread running: 49
thread running: 48
thread running: 47
thread running: 46

//Going down...

thread running: 17
thread running: 16
thread running: 15
thread running: 14
thread running: 13
thread running: 12
thread running: 11
thread running: 10
thread running: 10
thread running: 8
thread running: 7
thread running: 6
thread running: 5
thread running: 4
```

And then it stops at 4 or 3 or 2 (different each time). I waited a few minutes, but it didn't go down nor the code after the Parallel.ForEach gets executed.

The timeout for the request is 5000, the threads are 50.

Heres the other code for the checking:

```
private bool CheckProxy(string proxy, string domainToCheckWith, int timeout)
{
    try
    {
        WebRequest req = WebRequest.Create(domainToCheckWith);
        req.Proxy = new WebProxy(proxy);
        req.Timeout = timeout;
        var response = (HttpWebResponse) req.GetResponse();
        string responseString = ReadResponseString(response);

        if (responseString.Contains("SOMETHING HERE"))
        {
            OnGoodProxy(proxy);
            return true;
        }
        if (responseString.Contains("SOMEOTHERTHINGHERE"))
        {
            OnBadProxy(proxy);
            return false;
        }
        OnBadProxy(proxy);
        return false;
    }
    catch (WebException ex)
    {
        OnBadProxy(proxy);
        return false;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        OnLog(ex.Message, Color.Red);
        return false;
    }
}
```

Stop function:

```
public void StopChecking()
{
    try
    {
        if (_cts != null && mainThread.IsAlive)
        {
            if (_cts.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                mainThread.Abort();
                OnLog("Hard aborting Filter Threads...", Color.DarkGreen);
                while (mainThread.IsAlive) ;
                OnComplete();
                isRunning = false;
            }
            else
            {
                _cts.Cancel();
                OnLog("Soft aborting Filter Threads...", Color.DarkGreen);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        OnLog(ex.Message, Color.Red);
    }
}
```

IMPORTANT EDIT:

I added this to the CeckProxy function:

```
        Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
        sw.Start();
        string responseString = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
        sw.Stop();
```

This is the result of the last few threads:

```
thread running: 6
4449
thread running: 5
72534
thread running: 4
180094
thread running: 3
```

why is this so long? I mean 180 seconds?!

Comment: Do you ever actually call _cts.Cancel(). I can't see it anywhere.

Comment: @brumScouse I didn't add that part, but I can. I'll edit the OP in a second

Comment: I'd hazard a guess that the _cts in StopChecking must be scoped to the class the method lives?  I noticed that _cts is newed up each time in your CheckProxies method, is this intentional? My point being that _cts here has got to be the same  as the one in StopChecking  (I'm just checking)

Comment: `private CancellationTokenSource _cts;`
it's a field inside the class! 
and yes it's intentional. Each time I want to process new proxies I have to generate a new CancellationTokenSource

Comment: I was wondering what about changing Thread to a Task and passing through the cancellation token source. I am just wondering whether the Thread being newed up captures the cts...

Comment: It seems like they are going to end after a long time period (a few minutes, so it's far more than the timeout!)

Comment: So they do end, in the end! its just a while later...?

Comment: @brumScouse Ok, I tested it again. The stop after a couple of minutes (5+ mins.)
I have no idea were in my code they stop so long :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out myself.

I now read the response continuous and check with a stopwatch (and request.ReadWriteTimeout) that the reading part stops after a specific time (In my case `readTimeout`) is reached. Code

```
HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(domainToCheckWith);
            req.Proxy = new WebProxy(proxy);
            req.Timeout = timeout;
            req.ReadWriteTimeout = readTimeout;
            req.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.AcceptEncoding, "deflate,gzip");
            req.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.Deflate | DecompressionMethods.GZip;

            byte[] responseByte = new byte[1024];
            string responseString = string.Empty;

            sw.Start();
            using (WebResponse res = req.GetResponse())
            {
                using (Stream stream = res.GetResponseStream())
                {
                    while (stream.Read(responseByte, 0, responseByte.Length) > 0)
                    {
                        responseString += Encoding.UTF8.GetString(responseByte);
                        if(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds > (long)timeout)
                            throw new WebException();
                    }

                }
            }
            sw.Stop();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try lock inside try to lock the object

```
Object lockObject = new Object();
try
{
    Parallel.ForEach(proxies, new ParallelOptions {MaxDegreeOfParallelism = threads, CancellationToken = _cts.Token}, prox =>
    {
        Interlocked.Increment(ref running);
        Console.WriteLine("thread running: {0}", running);
        try
        {
            lock(lockObject)
            {
                //code.............
            }
        }
        catch
        {
        }
    }
}
catch
{
}
```

Comment: It works. But now it's not a real multithreading anymore because it waits till the previous thread is finished / the lock is released!
So this actually doesn't help me!

Comment: You would have to do something like this ParallelOptions pOptions = new ParallelOptions(); than inside your try catch block or maybe inside if else you will have to call  pOptions.CancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested(); or you could also have ...,proxy, (i, loopstate)=> than inside try catch you need to loopstate.Stop();

Comment: @Davidson I also tried that, but it's the same result